# HTTPHandler Note Hitting the the breakpoint in VS2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send some Async Data to the server form SP webpart.

I added the HttpHandler to the Layout folder in webpartproject and registered it in web.config file for the SharePoint site. But the problem is My handler Processrequest() is not executing (can't be debug too). I'm trying to get this done for two days now. I'm pretty new to SharePoint. Please help me  get this done.

I have attached  the codes and screen shot here.

This is usercontrol jQuery method for posting data to server.

```
 $("#SendAsync").click(function () {
        alert("fireing");

        var txtsendername = $('[id$=txtName]').val();
        var txtemail = $('[id$=txtboxEmail]').val();
        var RequestType = $('[id$=ddlRequestType]').val();
        var txtcontent = $('[id$=TxtAreaReq_Content]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Layouts/SendUsEmail/Handler1.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            data: "{ 'a': '"+txtsendername+"' }",
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("sent to the server" );
                $("#lblerror2").text("ok");

            },
            error: function (data) { alert("ERRO: " + data.status); },
            timeout: 15000
        });
    });
```

and this the Processrequest() method.

```
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var a = context.Request.Params["a"];
        Getdata(a);
        context.Response.Write("ajax" + a.ToString());
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

This is the hanlder Registration code

```
      <add name="Handler1" path="/_Layouts/SendUsEmail/Handler1.ashx" verb="*" type="SendUsEmail.Layouts.SendUsEmail.Handler1,SendUsEmail.VisualWebPart1,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neatral,PublicKeytoken=71e9bce111e9429c"/>
```

and finally this is the .ahsx page code.

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %><%@ AssemblyName="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %><%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="SendUsEmail.Layouts.SendUsEmail.Handler1" %>
```

When I'm posting data it's firing Success method as well, but not hitting  Handler at all.

When I use the browser I can see data like this.

[image: Data will be appear like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Ajax code, we read:

```
url: "/Layouts/SendUsEmail/Handler1.ashx",
```

While it should be:

```
url: "/_Layouts/SendUsEmail/Handler1.ashx",
```

note the '_' in front of "Layouts".

Comment: thank you i was out from office,cause of weekend, you saved me..i have been searching tw0 days because if this//..thank you very much.

Comment: var a = context.Request.Params["a"]; now this parameter is empty,

Comment: i tried   var a = context.Request["a"]; also no help.

Comment: You post your data as a JSON string to the server. Thus you need to read the data from the body, and deserialize the JSON it contains.

Comment: Code to get the raw string posted to the server from your ashx is:  
  
            HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);  
            System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);  
            string requestFromPost = reader.ReadToEnd();  
  
You then need to de-JSONify it.

Comment: could you give me a example?

Comment: I'd suggest you to post a new question, maybe an ASP.NET one, since this now deals with general Web programming (read JSON POST data from ashx).
But I already gave you the part to get the posted data as a string: you only have to deseralize it.

Comment: thank you i fixed it easily by javascripterializer obj.have a nice day